# Build a dynamic ranking column that will update when a slicer is selected

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to build a dynamic rank column that will update when a slicer is selected.  There are 2 slicers on the page: RegionalManager and SalesManager

There is only one table, say tblSales.  I have tried various combinations of RANKX but nothing seems to work.  Can someone help me with this? Here is a sample data and scenarios.

```
RegionalManager SalesManager    SalesPerson Sales   Rank
Bill             Patty          John         20      6
Bill             Patty          Sally        10      7
Bill             Patty          Connie       30      4
Bill             Connie         Jim          40      3
Bill             Connie         Amanda       70      1
Zack             Tracy          Trevor        5      8
Zack             Matt           Breanna      25      5
Zack             Mike           Pam          45      2

If I filter on Bill the Rank should be this:
RegionalManager SalesManager    SalesPerson Sales   Rank
Bill             Patty          John         20      4
Bill             Patty          Sally        10      5
Bill             Patty          Connie       30      3
Bill             Connie         Jim          40      2
Bill             Connie         Amanda       70      1

If I filter on Bill and Connie the Rank should be this:
RegionalManager SalesManager    SalesPerson Sales   Rank
Bill             Connie         Jim          40      2
Bill             Connie         Amanda       70      1
```

Comment: Calculated columns are static and don’t update on filter changes.

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a measure as follows:

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(tblSales), CALCULATE( SUM(tblSales[Sales])))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi David, when I add the DAX expression I get the following error message: A circular dependency was detected: tblSales[Sales].

Comment: Mike - if you follow the instructions exactly as posted, it works. I don't know what your wider model looks like but the simple example provided works as posted.